# I would like to find the value of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Write the function $f(z)=z+(1/z)$ where $z$ is not equal to zero. in the form $f(z)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$ and we know that $z$ is complex number

Comment: Your post needs some editing. Use Mathjax.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: You should use the substitution $z=re^{i\theta}=r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta\equiv g(r,\theta)+i h(r,\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

It can be written as $$\left(re^{i\theta}+\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{r}\right)=r({\cos}\theta+i{\sin}\theta)+\frac{1}{r}({\cos}\theta-i{\sin}\theta)$$ where $|z|=r$.

Comment: that is incorrect! Don't hurry too much:)

Comment: Should i write cosh

Comment: $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{r}$

Comment: See put i in $z+1/z$ you get 0 which is real

Comment: @Mos Black i have edited